# Use a string variable as input for Set-Content -Path

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that loops through textfiles an replaces the letter a by b

> $fileList = Get-ChildItem  C:\Projekte\ps
>
> foreach ($i in $fileList){ (Get-Content -Path $i.FullName ) -replace 'a' , 'b'    | Set-Content -Path  $i.FullName  }

I works, and the result is written back to the original files. I need to write the content back to a new file. The name of the file is the original file but wit the extension ".new"

I expected something like

> Set-Content -Path  $i.FullName + '.new'

but thats obviously wrong.

Whats the right syntax for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you )at list) filter text files so replace wont happen for other file extensions that may reside in that folder:

```
$fileList = Get-ChildItem D:\Scripts\Temp -Filter *.txt

foreach($i in $fileList)
{
    $path = Join-Path -Path $i.DirectoryName -ChildPath ($i.BaseName + '.new')
    (Get-Content -Path $i.FullName) -replace 'a','b' | Set-Content -Path $path
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that I only want to work on some specific files, but that I need to keep the old files untouched save the changed files with a new name. But the filter is a good addition to the script anyway.

Comment: Use the -Include parameter to filter multiple extensions: -Include *.txt,*.log. The code does exactly what you're looking for, it gets the content of the specified files, replace the content based on the regex (replace) pattern and writes the new content to new files. It doesn't change the original files.

Comment: You right. I did not read the Set-Content -Path $path. It was too late!